cp: cannot create regular file '/opt/MobaXterm_Portable_v24.0.zip': Permission denied
I am learning linux CLI, I wanted to put downloaded file in /opt directory but it is showing me an error.
cp: cannot create regular file '/opt/MobaXterm_Portable_v24.0.zip': Permission denied
Can anyone confirm what is wrong with it ?
I have changed permission of that of file by using chmod 777 and file name.
